# Graphical interface

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

When I start my Pi, it boots to text and asks for the password. How do I start graphical version?

I tried holding the <kbd>shift</kbd> key when starting up, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can change how your Pi boots using the `raspi-config` script.

1. From a command prompt start `raspi-config` by typing the following:

   ```
   sudo raspi-config
   ```
2. select option **3 Boot Options**,
3. then select option **3 Desktop** or **Desktop Autologin** (The first will require the password, the second will not).
4. Click **Ok** and
5. click **Finish** to exit `raspi-config`.

Finally reboot to test your changes.

FYI holding down the <kbd>shift</kbd> key determines whether the Pi boots to safe mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to start it once:

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Assuming you are using the standard Raspbian.